# How can I use LEMMISI effectively?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010, desktop-dungeons

I've always been converting this glyph immediately.  Revealing three random tiles not only isn't very helpful, it actually removes future healing potential.  I can get the same healing effect from just revealing three tiles that are actually near me.  So why would I ever want to take up one of my glyph slots with LEMMISI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's basically meant more as a primitive healing factor, which is why there's actually a bonus point reward for using LEMMISI repeatedly in one stage. Don't use it to rob your future healing potential, use it *as* your healing potential.

If you're not a Wizard or Berserker, you make even with the mana cost. Wizards will regain 1 Mana, while Berserkers will spend 2 extra Mana. It's primarily for usage when you don't want to perform exploration directly. Some reasons you might want to do so include:

- As a primer to actual exploration. You have some damage, want to heal it before advancing. Use LEMMISI to possibly see what might be a better direction that you want to head in, rather than bruting through the darkness towards what may have been the worse direction to go.
- As an extension to the above, use it while facing off multiple visible opponents at once. This lets you get the normal healing effect of exploration while exploring the more remote parts of the map, instead of what is right near you.
- If you're in a situation where you can't directly explore due to big tough fellows in the way, but you can defeat one opponent if you had the aid of exploration regeneration (either just to get back to full health, or because you can beat the enemy's regeneration rate), then this helps.
- You've run out of normally reachable exploration, and there's some blackness that's buried inside of a bunch of stone blocks. Unless you're a transmuter (in which case you don't want LEMMISI in the first place), it's far cheaper to use LEMMISI than to dig through the walls.
- If you're a Sorceror, then you get extra healing on account of your ability. Since the mana cost equals the amount you'd regain from actual exploration, it's actually better healing.

Comment: While it "sort of" costs 0 mana, that's really only true if I have full mana at the time of casting it, since otherwise I could get the same healing effect AND extra mana by revealing squares manually.  Still, I do see that there might be some niche uses for it.  Cool!

Comment: Thinking about it more, that fourth bullet actually seems pretty powerful.  If you leave LEMMISI on the ground until you're ready to fight the boss, you usually have some other glyph that you no longer need.  Convert it, pick up LEMMISI, and use it repeatedly to reveal all the black squares that are unreachable.  There's usually at least 20 of them, which means it is 1-2 full heals at no mana cost!  Of course the boss heals too, but you can use it to heal right before the fight, or during if you have APHEELSIK.

Comment: @bwarner Slightly weakened with APHEELSIK on account of the the lack of Mana regen and the new requirement to re-cast it, but exactly, it's pretty potent to leave it until the end (where it won't be taking up one of your slots). That said keep in mind as you approach the end, you'll lose 1-2 mana as a non-Wizard if the number of remaining darkness is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Berserkers don't break even from a mana perspective - they lose 2 per use assuming there are 3 undiscovered blocks per use - but then as a berserker, you're probably not using other glyphs that much anyway, and you might be quite willing to trade 2 mana for some healing you wouldn't otherwise get.

Comment: @Dave Good point, I forgot about the mana cost penalty that Berserkers have... kinda because it makes me rarely use mana as a Berserker.